# 90 degree pivot steering system to allow vehicles to move sideways

Tags: mechanical-engineering, automotive-engineering

Are there any restrictions that would not allow a steering system to cause a vehicle to be able to move sideways - at 90 degrees from the convention direction of travel?

[image]

Comment: Nothing new here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ki9otMeiRP0 ;)

Comment: That is not 90 deg in the image...

Answer (score 1):

Technically yes you can design it here is an [example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c_1Sg1dJ7i8), however designers have to develop a locking system to prevent the back wheels while the car moves in a curve otherwise the car starts spinning around itself. The only advantage here is easy parking but it makes the whole system very complexe for engineers and mechanics, think about the extra weight.